# How to get list of all programs that i have opened?

Tags: python, pyautogui

Basically i am trying to build simple app blocker, but ive tried alot of solutions but they always return window handle rather than the name of the program that is running

i ran the program and this is the output
Ask a public question - Stack Overflow - Google Chrome

i only want to get The name of the program so Google Chrome

```
import pyautogui
import AppOpener

# blocked window
blocked = "Microsoft Edge"

#this prints list of all the window.
windows = pyautogui.getAllWindows()

for window in windows:
    app = window.title


    app_split_list = str(app).split("-")
# the reason why im splitting it is because the window.title is in format like this:
New tab - Personal - Microsoft​ Edge


    for item in app_split_list:
        print(item)
        if blocked in item:
            print("found")
            AppOpener.close(blocked)
            break

#this didnt work because the getAllWindows() returned New tab - Personal - Microsoft​ Edge ( Microsoft Edge is with 2 spaces in between so it didnt got recognized.)
```

Ive tried using pyautogui module but it i cant figure out how to get the exact programs, not window handles.

i ran the program and this is the output:
Ask a public question - Stack Overflow - Google Chrome
YouTube - Personal - Microsoft​  Edge

as you can see its the name of the program is at the end, but is there a way to get just the program name. Ive made app block around it but often it doesnt work and doesnt recognize the window handles as programs

Comment: Maybe print `app_split_list` to see what it looks like? It might not be what you expect

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your for loop:

```py
# remove additional whitespaces between words
app = " ".join(window.title.split())

# check if app string contains the blocked keywords
if blocked in app:
    print("found")
    AppOpener.close(blocked)
```

To list processes running under your username:

```py
import pwd, os, psutil

cur_user = pwd.getpwuid(os.getuid())[0]

for p in psutil.pids():
    if psutil.Process(p).username() == cur_user:
        print(psutil.Process(p).name())
```